# How can I pass a function pointer as a template value argument without creating a function object in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I've seen many variants of this question asked here, but I still feel my specific case is different.

My goal is wrapping a C API that looks like this:

```cpp
TF_Buffer* buf = TF_AllocateBuffer();
// ...
TF_DeleteBuffer(buf);
```

Since I have many of these objects, I'd love to create a generic type named `handle` that could hold a given pointer and call the appropriate deallocator upon destruction. My imagined use case would be

```cpp
class buffer : public handle<TF_Buffer, TF_DeleteBuffer> {
public:
  buffer(TF_Buffer* b): handle(b) {}
}
```

unfortunately I'm unable to get this to work since `TF_DeleteBuffer` is a simple function (of type `void TF_DeleteBuffer(TF_Buffer*)`). I did manage to work around the issue with creating a function object for the function, so the following does work

```cpp
template<typename Obj, typename Deleter>
class handle {
public:
  Obj* obj;

  handle(Obj* o): obj(o) {};
  ~handle() { if (obj) Deleter()(obj); }
};

struct buffer_deleter {
  void operator()(TF_Buffer* b) { TF_DeleteBuffer(b); }
};

class buffer : public handle<TF_Buffer, buffer_deleter> {
public:
  buffer(TF_Buffer* b): handle(b) {}
}
```

but it feels dirty having to define the `buffer_deleter` class just for this purpose. I'd imagine something like this ought to work (with or without the `std::function`)

```cpp
template<typename Obj, std::function<void(Obj*)> Deleter>
class handle {
  // ...
}
```

but I can't find a way to make the compiler happy. From what I understand, this is somewhat similar to `std::unique_ptr` which accepts a deleter type object, vs `std::shared_ptr` which accepts a deleter function pointer and stores it in the shared object. I don't mind storing the pointer explicitly (and using extra memory), but at the same time, given I'll be creating lots of these types, I'd like to have some way of making it syntactically nice. I really do not want to pass the deleter pointer to each instance of the object being created, which is why I'm trying to hide it in the template.

Comment: I hit that recently and my conclusion was "nope". I'm pretty sure that your working solution is *the* one to use, and there are reasons to `unique_ptr` using that as well. Except that it also asks for the instance of the deleter, as opposed to creating a default one.

Comment: @akub Arnold Could you declare the class buffer as a template class?

Comment: Can the deleter function vary? If not you can just create your `handle` class without template parameters and call `TF_DeleteBuffer` in its destructor.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes I can define buffer to be anything, since then I can just store the specialization under a reasonable name

Comment: @MikeLischke there are many different combinations of "Obj" and "Deleter" so that's why the `handle` is made generic ... I basically want to wrap a whole bunch of C API with RAII

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) as function pointer.

```
template<typename Obj, void(*Deleter)(Obj*)>
class handle {
public:
  Obj* obj;

  handle(Obj* o): obj(o) {};
  ~handle() { if (obj) Deleter(obj); }
};
```

And use it like

```
class buffer : public handle<TF_Buffer, &TF_DeleteBuffer> {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! It seems the `&TF_DeleteBuffer` is not needed and just passing `TF_DeleteBuffer` works (I guess functions get casted to function pointers?) ... anyway, I guess shame on me for not knowing function syntax properly when trying this hehe

Comment: @JakubArnold Yes, for non-member functions and static member functions `&` is optional because of function-to-pointer decay.

Comment: I think a template alias (`using buffer = handle<TF_Buffer, &TF_DeleteBuffer>`) would be much simpler and cleaner to use here, if available, of course.

Comment: @JakubArnold Note: this is a demonstration snippet not fit for real-life program; you should modify it to respect the rule of 0/3/5 ;)

Comment: Can std::function be used here instead of the function pointer?

Comment: @Demolishun As template parameter, No.

Comment: @YSC yeah my actual handle has a deleted copy ctor/= and proper move ctor/=, but I removed it from the snippet to make code here less ugly

Answer (score 1):

I'd reuse `std::shared_ptr`. It just works in all cases and have been thoroughly tested:

```
template<class Buffer, class Destructor>
auto make_handle(Buffer buffer, Destructor dstr)
{ return std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer_t<Buffer>>(buffer, dstr); }
```

Usage:

```
auto h = make_handle(TF_AllocateBuffer(), TF_DeleteBuffer);
```

Full demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b12e4adc559cbfd7

---

As a bonus, you can now *copy* the handle and it does The Right Thing:

```
{
    auto h2 = h;
} // does not free h's buffer until h is out of scope :)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer:
Depending on your use-case, using a `type trait`-based approach (similar to `std::allocator`) would be a cleaner solution.
(Especially if you have many different handle types that you need to wrap with `handle<>`)

Example:

```cpp
// Boilerplate.
// Assume TF_Buffer and Foobar_Buffer would be handle types
struct TF_Buffer {};
struct Foobar_Buffer {};

// TF_Buffer functions
TF_Buffer* TF_AllocateBuffer() { return new TF_Buffer(); };
void TF_DeleteBuffer(TF_Buffer* buf) { delete buf; }

// Foobar_Buffer functions
Foobar_Buffer* Foobar_AllocateBuffer() { return new Foobar_Buffer(); };
void Foobar_DeleteBuffer(Foobar_Buffer* buf) { delete buf; }

// Generic handle_allocator for all handles that are not specified.
// if you don't have a generic way of allocating handles simply leave them out,
// which will lead to a compile-time error when you use handle<> with a non-specialized type.
template<typename handle_type>
struct handle_allocator {
    /*
      static handle_type* allocate() {
          // Generic handle allocate
      }
      static void deallocate(handle_type* handle) {
          // Generic handle delete
      }
    */
};

// Traits for TF_Buffer
template<>
struct handle_allocator<TF_Buffer> {
    static TF_Buffer* allocate() { return TF_AllocateBuffer(); }
    static void deallocate(TF_Buffer* handle) { TF_DeleteBuffer(handle); }
};

// Traits for Foobar_Buffer
template<>
struct handle_allocator<Foobar_Buffer> {
    static Foobar_Buffer* allocate() { return Foobar_AllocateBuffer(); }
    static void deallocate(Foobar_Buffer* handle) { Foobar_DeleteBuffer(handle); }
};

template<typename Obj, typename allocator = handle_allocator<Obj>>
class handle {
public:
  Obj* obj;

  // you can also use the traits to default-construct a handle
  handle() : obj(allocator::allocate()) {}
  handle(Obj* o): obj(o) {};

  ~handle() { if (obj) allocator::deallocate(obj); }
};

class buffer : public handle<TF_Buffer> {
public:
  buffer(TF_Buffer* b): handle(b) {}
};

// This will not work, because the generic handle_allocator
// doesn't have allocate() and deallocate() functions defined
/*
  struct NotWorking {};
  handle<NotWorking> w;
*/
```

[Example in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/wTKDP3)

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not care much about types of functions. For instance, check this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int func(char* str) { cout << str << endl; return strlen(str); }
template<class T> T executor(T f) { return f; }
int main()
{
    int x = executor(func)("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

The only thing it cares, when it comes to using the real types, they must satisfy the operation performed inside the class. It is perfectly OK to do in Visual C++ something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void strdtor(char* str)
{
    cout << "deleting " << str << endl;
    delete[] str;
}
template <class T, typename TDeletor> class memorizer
{
    TDeletor& dtor;
    T buffer;
public:
    memorizer(T buf, TDeletor dt) : buffer(buf), dtor(dt){}
    ~memorizer(){dtor(buffer);}
};
int main()
{
    char* c = new char[10];
    sprintf_s(c, 10, "hello");
    memorizer<char*, void(char*)> m(c, strdtor);
    return 0;
}
```

As lambda:

```
char* d = new char[10];
sprintf_s(d, 10, "world");
memorizer<char*, void(char*)> m2(
       d, 
       [](char* x) -> void 
       {
          cout << "lambla  deleting " << x << endl;
          delete[] x; 
       });
```

Comment: note: to define template-argument, the keywords `class` and `typename` are exact synonyms. Maybe choose one and stick to it.

Comment: @YSC that's correct. That's why there is no reason to care much about that

Comment: (joking) Are you familiar with my favourite quality indicator of source code: wtf/line?

Comment: @YSC one wtf per line is okay, 2 to 3 per line and we may have a problem?